# Is there any methods to return CompletableFuture response to SoapUI

Tags: java, asynchronous, soapui, completable-future, ws

I’m doing the request to soap webservice due to `CompletableFuture#runAsync` methods. The request is sent from SoapUI client. I see the response in logs. But the response is not viewed on SoapUI client.

Is it possible to return a `CompletableFuture` to SoapUI?

Comment: Which framework are you using to implement your Soap service? Could you show some sample code?